# Do defeated keeps increase the hand size for allies?

Tags: mage-knight

Defeated keeps increase the hand size by 1 for each keep owned when you end your turn adjacent or in a keep. Does it also increase the hand size for allies in the coop games?

If not, is there some coop situation where an ally's hand size is increased? I feel like I've read a ruling on this but can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** Each ally's hand limit is increased by the number of keeps they themselves own.

The general rules for drawing cards only refer to your own keeps, since cooperative rules are ignored in the general section. However, on Page 13, under *Team Rules*, the rulebook states:

> When in or adjacent to an allied keep, his
>   Hand limit is increased, but only for the keeps he owns himself.
>   That means, if close to an allied keep but he has no keeps of his
>   own, his Hand limit is not modified.

Don't forget that a city hand limit bonus does not stack with this bonus, you simply get whichever is better. This also applies to your allies.